# What is the current helper as back() was in lumen 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a small project written in Lumen 5.6 and currently I am stucked in the problem that in my view, I need to redirect a user back to the page he came from. I've seen that before in older versions there was a back() method or redirect()->back(). Now they are not available anymore, is there a solution in the framework for this?

Comment: redirect()->back() works fine I use this all of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`back`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-back) helper method to return him to the previous `route state`

**EDIT:** There is no support for `back` functionality in `Lumen` as I can see

Comment: When I used the back() helper an error is thrown that the back() doesn't exist.

Comment: Well as I can see there is no `back` helper method nor as a part of `redirect` or `response` helpers, not even `=< 5.5` versions, I searched in lumens github repo for

Comment: You need to run `redirect()->back()` and Nikola's answer will work. I'm running laravel version 5.6 also and use `redirect()->back()` all of the time.

Comment: But he is using `Lumen` and as I can see there is no `back` helper, like there is no support for `back` at all

Comment: I tried the above, redirect()->back() but as Nikola said, there is no support for it in Lumen.